# Does tensorflow propagate gradients through a pdf

Tags: tensorflow

Lets say, a distribution function is defined as below:

```
dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(mu, sigma)
```

and a sample is drawn from the distribution

```
val = dist.pdf(x)
```

and this value is used in a model to predict a variable

```
X_hat = f(val)
loss = tf.norm(X_pred-X_hat, ord=2)
```

and if I want to optimize the variables mu and sigma to reduce my prediction error can I do the following?

```
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-03).minimize(loss, var_list=[mu, sigma])
```

I am interested in knowing if the gradient routines are propagated through the normal distribution, or should I expect some issues because I am taking gradients over the parameters defining a distribution

Comment: Theoretically, no, but there is a well-known reparameterization trick. Generate a standard Gaussian noise `z` (perhaps with `tf.random_normal`), and do `x = z * std + mu`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I like your approach to optimizing std and mu.

Answer (score 8):

**tl;dr:** Yes, gradient back propagation will work correctly with `tf.distributions.Normal`.

`dist.pdf(x)` does not draw a sample from the distribution, but rather returns the probability density function at `x`. This is probably not what you wanted.

To get a random sample, what you really want is to call `dist.sample()`. For many random distributions, the dependency of a random sample on the parameters is nontrivial and will not necessarily be backpropable.

However, as @Richard_wth pointed out, specifically for the normal distribution, it is possible through reparametrization to get a simple dependency on the location and scale parameters (`mu` and `sigma`).

In fact, in [the implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b7e38a5f2a310599e9d4cab2bd95a43dd18018d6/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/normal.py#L186) of `tf.contrib.distributions.Normal` (recently migrated to `tf.distributions.Normal`), that is exactly how `sample` is implemented:

```
def _sample_n(self, n, seed=None):
  ...
  sampled = random_ops.random_normal(shape=shape, mean=0., stddev=1., ...)
  return sampled * self.scale + self.loc
```

Consequently, if you provide scale and location parameters as tensors, then backpropagation will work correctly on those tensors.

Note that this backpropagation is inherently random: It will vary depending on the random draw of the normal Gaussian variable. However, in the long run (over many training examples), this is likely to work as you expect.

Comment: Hi I understand the random sampling and convergence through the law of large numbers, I wanted a probability density at x which would not be "random". The link you provide to the implementation calculates a "z-score" using the location and scale parameters, so would an optimizer optimize these through gradients?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. But if there's nothing random in what you're doing, you could also just compute the formula for the pdf yourself.